# Using Bert to convert Vectors to Word in pytorch

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch

I am using Bert for sentence embedding and I would like to then take that embedding and convert back to word. How would I go about doing this? Is this even possible?

Comment: With bert, it must practically be difficult as bert embeddings are based on position as well, you call it positional embeddings.

Comment: Also, taking a look at cosine distance should be helpful in case of other word2vec models.

Comment: Hey Ashwin, Thanks for your response. Is it possible, to find the nearest neighboring bert embedded vector for a specific bert embedded vector?

Comment: One simple approach that I can think of is, generate embedding for each word in vocab, that is generated with an assumption of being 1st word.  Then, you can use cosine distace.

Comment: Also, bert uses Masked laguage model, where it tries to predict the word. In such case, you must be able to obtain the word based in embedding even by considering the context and the psoition. But, I an not sure how exactly bert does this.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a inverse dictionary for this. For every word you vectorize, store it in a dictionary and later just fetch the word for each vector.

Comment: The vectors corresponding to each word output by BERT change depending on the surrounding context words. It would be useless to create a dictionary with vectors as the keys because (a) the vector for a given word will change in different sentences (b) vectors are not hashable (you could circumvent by converting to a tuple, but using finite precision floating-point filled tuples as dict keys is a [really bad idea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#cite_note-Christiansen_Perl-69)).